# Windows Phone store country specific collection

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone, windows-phone-store

When you go to Windows Phone store -> apps -> Collections you can see list of different collections which include region specific collection, "The Ukraine Collection" in my case. What would I do as a developer to see my app in this collection? Should I limit the app to only Ukrainian market?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to do a great app. The country collection is the best apps from the specific country.

Comment: So, what are concrete parameters to go in? I see there an app with 13 ratings and average is 4, which is not so many. Is it described somewhere?

Comment: You need an app with a great design respecting guidline. You need to create an originaly app. If you want, you can create app for to discover UK or something but it is not necessary. The collection was not filled with a robot, you should be a great app and if MS UK like your app, it will be ok and they add your app to collection. Dont forget to publish your app in multi language :)

Comment: So it's manually added by local MS? If so, could you please, provide some link where this mentioned.